# Члены, не члены, нечлены

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Касательно организаций, основанных на членстве. Как правильно писать тех, кто в членстве не состоит, *не члены* или *нечлены*? Допустимо ли слитное написание? Смущает то, что есть, к примеру, *гражданин*, *негражданин* и *не гражданин России*.

Comment: Без контекста разговаривать невозможно.

Answer (score 3):

Современные правила орфографии предполагают слитное написание "нечлены", хотя это новшество еще мало используется на практике (в одном случае из десяти). Ранее предполагалось, что такие написания уместны только при наличии в предложении обеих форм, например:

"Я во время войны был мальчиком, а она взрослым человеком и видела, как в эвакуации члены Союза имели право на комнату, и лучшие продуктовые карточки, и дрова, а нечлены, как Цветаева, не имели".

Правило [Академический справочник](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=79#pp79)

"НЕ" пишется слитно, если существительные и прилагательные в сочетании с "НЕ" обозначают непринадлежность к какому-либо разряду лиц или явлений, напр.: неврачи, нефраниузы, немарксисты, нехристиане, неспециалисты, немосквичи, нерусские, недемократы, непоэты, нетермины, неметаллы, нестихи.

Comment: В правление избраны пять членов товарищества и два нечлена. В правление избраны пять членов и два не члена товарищества. В правление избраны пять членов и два не совсем члена. Не член, а просто человек. Ведь так? Слитно, когда простое указание на какой-то контингент, а раздельно, когда именно усилие делается на отрицание?

Comment: Согласно правилу,  в приведенных примерах написание слитное, так как  отрицание отсутствует. Нечлен - это человек, не принадлежащий в определенной группе, то есть слово с конкретным смыслом, которое может применяться в утвердительных конструкциях. Сравните: (1) Он не член профсоюза (отрицание).  (2)Нет ли здесь дискриминации в отношении нечленов профсоюза (утверждение).

Comment: А как же это: "негражданин" и "не гражданин России". Я думаю, в случае с Россией надо писать раздельно, так как без отрицания получаем невозможное что-то: "негражданин России". Нет таких!

Comment: Аналогично, "нечлен профсоюза" - это не ложится на восприятие никак. Потому что нет такого контингента с принадлежностью профсоюзу, как нечлены. Здесь просится к акценту отрицание. Я думаю, надо так: "нечлены", но "не члены профсроюза".

Comment: В отличие от нечленов профсоюза его члены имеют право на второй источник получения социальных благ ― из средств профсоюза. (Если перед существительным с не имеется определение или предлог. Наличие этих слов является признаком того, что не с данным существительным образует единое слово).